# phpmyadmin: Instert: Continue insertion with (change limit)

Tags: database, insert, phpmyadmin, row, cell

In phpmyadmin (3.4.10.1deb1), the Insert tab, it shows these options:

```
Continue insertion with: 1,2,5,10,15,20,30,40
```

I need to change these numbers and add higher values..  Where can I edit this? or add these numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 3.4.10.1, it's in tbl_change.php, line 1128.